# Meaning of 'sp_renamedb'

Tags: sql-server-2008

I did rename to the database. I`m following query

`EXEC sp_renamedb 'old_name', 'new_name'`

```
Here, I want to meaning of
```

> sp_renamedb

Comment: that stored proc  renames the database ,are you expecting some thing other than that

Comment: you are told correctly. I want to ful form of 'sp'.. thank u Gameiswar

Answer (score 1):

**sp_renamedb** means change the name of database.

Exp.

sp_renamedb [ @dbname = ] 'old_name' , [ @newname = ] 'new_name'

Please refer [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186217.aspx) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

`Sp_Rename` Proc renames database..If you  want full text,you can get using `sp_helptext` like below

```
sp_helptext 'sp_rename'
```

which gives

```
create procedure sys.sp_rename

    @objname    nvarchar(1035),     -- up to 4-part "old" name

    @newname    sysname,            -- one-part new name

    @objtype    varchar(13) = null  -- identifying the name

as

/* DOCUMENTATION:

   [1]  To rename a table, the @objname (meaning OldName) parm can be

passed in totally unqualified or fully qualified.

   [2]  The SA or DBO can rename objects owned by lesser users,

without the need for SetUser.

   [3]  The Owner portion of a qualified name can usually be

passed in in the omitted form (as in MyDb..MyTab or MyTab).  The

typical exception is when the SA/DBO is trying to rename a table

where the @objname is present twice in sysobjects as a table

owned only by two different lesser users; requiring an explicit

owner qualifier in @objname.

   [4]  An unspecified Owner qualifier will default to the

current user if doing so will either resolve what would

otherwise be an ambiguity within @objtype, or will result

in exactly one match.

   [5]  If Database is part of the qualified @objname,

then it must match the current database.  The @newname parm can

never be qualified.

   [6]  Here are the valid @objtype values.  They correspond to

system tables which track each type:

      'column'  'database'  'index'  'object'  'userdatatype'  'statistics'

The @objtype parm is sometimes required.  It is always required

for databases.  It is required whenever ambiguities would

otherwise exist.  Explicit use of @objtype is always encouraged.

   [7]  Parms can use quoted_identifiers.  For example:

   Execute sp_rename 'amy."his table"','"her table"','object'

*/

    set nocount      on

    set ansi_padding on



    declare @objtypeIN      varchar(13),

        @objtypeINOrig      varchar(13),

            @objnameLen         int,

            @CurrentDb      sysname,

            @CountNumNodes  int,

            @UnqualOldName  sysname,

            @QualName1      sysname,

            @QualName2      sysname,

            @QualName3      sysname,

            @OwnAndObjName  nvarchar(517),  -- "[owner].[object]"

            @SchemaAndTypeName  nvarchar(517),  -- "[schema].[type]"

            @objid          int,

            @xtype          nchar(2),

            @indexstatsid       int,

            @colid          int,

            @cnstid         int,

            @xusertype      int,

            @schid          int,

            @objid_tmp      int,

            @xtype_tmp      nchar(2),

            @retcode        int,

            @published      bit     -- Indicates table is used in replication







    -- initial (non-null) settings

    select  @CurrentDb      = db_name(),

            @objtypeIN      = @objtype,

            @objtypeINOrig      = @objtype



    -- make type case insensitive

    select @objtype = lower(@objtypeIN collate Latin1_General_CI_AS)



    ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    -------------------  PHASE 10:  Simple parm edits  ---------------------

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------



    -- Valid rename-type param?

    if (@objtype is not null AND

        @objtype not in ('column', 'database', 'index', 'object', 'userdatatype', 'statistics'))

    begin

        raiserror(15249,-1,-1,@objtypeIN)

        return 1

    end

    -- null names?

    if (@newname IS null)

    begin

        raiserror(15223,-1,11,'NewName')

        return 1

    end

    if (@objname IS null)

    begin

        raiserror(15223,-1,-1,'OldName')

        return 1

    end



    --  Is NewName minimally valid?

    exec @retcode = sp_validname @newname

    if @retcode <> 0

    begin

        raiserror(15224,-1,15,@newname)

        return 1

    end



    --  Parse apart the perhaps dots-qualified old name.

    select @UnqualOldName = parsename(@objname, 1),

            @QualName1 = parsename(@objname, 2),

            @QualName2 = parsename(@objname, 3),

            @QualName3 = parsename(@objname, 4)

    if (@UnqualOldName IS Null)

    begin

        raiserror(15253,-1,-1,@objname)

        return 1

    end



    -- count name parts --

    select @CountNumNodes = (case

                when @QualName3 is not null then 4

                when @QualName2 is not null then 3

                when @QualName1 is not null then 2

                else 1

            end)

    if (@objtype  = 'database' AND @CountNumNodes > 1)

    begin

        raiserror(15395,-1,20,@objtypeIN)

        return 1

    end

    if (@objtype in ('object','userdatatype') AND @CountNumNodes > 3)

    begin

        raiserror(15225,-1,-1,@objname, @CurrentDb, @objtypeIN)

        return 1

    end



    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ------------------------   PHASE 15:  Lock Down Checks   ------------------

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------



    -- Check if this is an SDS session before applying checks. This is equivalent to chec eflSystemObjects

    if (serverproperty('EngineEdition') = 5)

    begin

        if ((@objtype = 'object' and (@QualName3 is not null or (@QualName2 is not null and @QualName2 != @CurrentDb))) or 

            (@objtype != 'database' and (@QualName3 is not null and @QualName3 != @CurrentDb)) )

        begin

            select @objnameLen = len(@objname)

            raiserror(40515,-1,-1, @objnameLen, @objname)

            return 1

        end

        if (@objtype = 'database')

        begin

            raiserror(40514,-1,-1, 'Renaming a given database with sp_rename')

            return 1

        end

    end



    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ----------------------  PHASE 20:  Settle Parm1ItemType  ------------------

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------



    ------------- database?

    if (@objtype  = 'database')

    begin

        execute @retcode = sys.sp_renamedb @UnqualOldName ,@newname -- de-docu old sproc

        if @retcode <> 0

            return 1

        return 0

    end



    BEGIN TRANSACTION



    ------------ type?

    if (@objtype = 'userdatatype' or @objtypeIN is null)

    begin

        select @xusertype = user_type_id, @schid = schema_id

            from sys.types where user_type_id = type_id(@objname)



        -- Lock scalar type exclusively and check permissions

        if not (@xusertype is null)

        begin



        -- cannot pass @objname as it is nvarchar(1035) and Invoke fails %%ScalarType does not compile with four part name.

        -- cross db type resolution is not allowed (already taken care of by type_id) so only two part name is required.

        if (@QualName1 is not null)

            select @SchemaAndTypeName = QuoteName(@QualName1) + '.' + QuoteName(@UnqualOldName)

        else

            select @SchemaAndTypeName = QuoteName(@UnqualOldName)



            EXEC %%ScalarType(MultiName = @SchemaAndTypeName).LockMatchID(ID = @xusertype, Exclusive = 1)

            if (@@error <> 0)

                select @xusertype = null

        end



        -- check for wrong param

        if ((@xusertype is not null AND @objtype <> 'userdatatype') OR

            (@xusertype is null AND @objtype = 'userdatatype'))

        begin

            COMMIT TRANSACTION

            raiserror(15248,-1,-1,@objtypeIN)

            return 1

        end



        if not (@xusertype is null)

            select  @objtype = 'userdatatype'



    end



    -- assuming column/index-name, obtain object/column id's

    if (@objtype in ('column', 'index', 'statistics') or @objtypeIN is null)

    begin

        if @QualName2 is not null

            select @objid = object_id(QuoteName(@QualName2) +'.'+ QuoteName(@QualName1))

        else

            select @objid = object_id(QuoteName(@QualName1))



        if not (@objid is null) -- nice try?

        begin



            -- obtain owner-qual object name

            select @schid = ObjectProperty(@objid, 'schemaid')

            select @OwnAndObjName = QuoteName(schema_name(@schid))+'.'+QuoteName(object_name(@objid))



            EXEC %%Object(MultiName = @OwnAndObjName).LockMatchID(ID = @objid, Exclusive = 1, BindInternal = 0)

            if @@error <> 0

                select @objid = null

            else

                select @xtype = type from sys.objects where object_id = @objid



        end

    end



    ------------ column?

    if (@objtype = 'column' or @objtypeIN is null)

    begin

        -- find column

        if (@xtype in ('U','V'))

            select @colid = column_id from sys.columns

                    where object_id = @objid and name = @UnqualOldName



        -- check for wrong param

        if ((@colid is not null AND @objtype <> 'column') OR

            (@colid is null AND @objtype = 'column'))

        begin

            COMMIT TRANSACTION

            raiserror(15248,-1,-1,@objtypeIN)

            return 1

        end



        -- remember if we've found a column

        if not (@colid is null)

        begin

            select @published = is_published from sys.objects where object_id = @objid

            if @published = 0

                select @published = is_merge_published from sys.tables where object_id = @objid



            if (@published <> 0)

                begin

                    COMMIT TRANSACTION

                    raiserror(15051,-1,-1)

                    return (0)

                end

            select @objtype = 'column'

        end

    end



    ------------ index?

    if (@objtype = 'index' or @objtypeIN is null)

    begin

        -- find index

        if (@xtype in ('U','V'))

            select @indexstatsid = indexproperty(@objid, @UnqualOldName, 'IndexID')



        if (@indexstatsid = 0) 

            set @indexstatsid = NULL;



        -- find columnstore index where there is no stats

        if (@indexstatsid is null)

            select @indexstatsid = index_id from sys.indexes

                    where object_id = @objid and name = @UnqualOldName and (type = 5 or type = 6)



        -- check for wrong param

        if ((@indexstatsid is not null AND @objtype <> 'index') OR

            (@indexstatsid is null AND @objtype = 'index'))         

        begin

            COMMIT TRANSACTION

            raiserror(15248,-1,-1,@objtypeIN)

            return 1

        end



        if not (@indexstatsid is null)

        begin

            select @objtype = 'index'

            select @cnstid = object_id, @xtype = type from sys.objects

                where name = @UnqualOldName and parent_object_id = @objid and type in ('PK','UQ')

        end

    end



    ------------ statistics?

    if (@objtype = 'statistics')

    begin

        select @indexstatsid = stats_id from sys.stats 

                    where object_id = @objid and name = @UnqualOldName



        -- check for wrong param

        if (@indexstatsid is null)

        begin

            COMMIT TRANSACTION

            raiserror(15248,-1,-1,@objtypeIN)

            return 1

        end 

    end



    ------------ object?

    if (@objtype = 'object' or @objtypeIN is null)

    begin

        -- get object id, type

        select @objid_tmp = object_id(@objname)



        if not (@objid_tmp is null)

        begin

            -- obtain owner-qual object name

            select @schid = ObjectProperty(@objid_tmp, 'schemaid')

            select @OwnAndObjName = QuoteName(schema_name(@schid))+'.'+QuoteName(object_name(@objid_tmp))



            EXEC %%Object(MultiName = @OwnAndObjName).LockMatchID(ID = @objid_tmp, Exclusive = 1, BindInternal = 0)

            if @@error <> 0

                select @objid_tmp = null

        end



        select @xtype_tmp = type

            from sys.objects where object_id = @objid_tmp



        -- if object is a system table, a Scalar function, or a table valued function, skip it.



        -- Cannot rename system table

        if @xtype_tmp = 'S'

            select @objid_tmp = NULL



        -- Locks parent object and increments schema_ver

        if not (@objid_tmp is null)

        begin



            if (@xtype_tmp in ('U'))

            begin



                select @published = is_merge_published | is_published from sys.tables where object_id = @objid_tmp

                if (@published <> 0)

                begin

                    COMMIT TRANSACTION

                    raiserror(15051,-1,-1)

                    return (0)

                end

            end



            -- parent already locked via locking object



        end



        -- check for wrong param

        if ((@objid_tmp is not null AND @objtype <> 'object') OR

            (@objid_tmp is null AND @objtype = 'object'))

        begin

            COMMIT TRANSACTION

            raiserror(15248,-1,-1,@objtypeIN)

            return 1

        end



        if not (@objid_tmp is null)

            select @objtype = 'object', @objid = @objid_tmp, @xtype = @xtype_tmp



    end



    ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    -------------------  PHASE 30:  More parm edits  --------------------

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------



    -- item type determined?

    if (@objtype is null)

    begin

        COMMIT TRANSACTION

        raiserror(15225,-1,-1,@objname, @CurrentDb, @objtypeIN)

        return 1

    end



    -- was the original name valid given this type?

    if (@objtype in ('object','userdatatype') AND @CountNumNodes > 3)

    begin

        COMMIT TRANSACTION

        raiserror(15225,-1,-1,@objname, @CurrentDb, @objtypeIN)

        return 1

    end



    -- verify db qualifier is current db

    if (@objtype in ('object','userdatatype'))

        select @QualName3 = @QualName2

    if (isnull(@QualName3, @CurrentDb) <> @CurrentDb)

    begin

        COMMIT TRANSACTION

        raiserror(15333,-1,-1,@QualName3)

        return 1

    end



    if (@objtype <> 'userdatatype')

    begin

        -- check if system object

        select @schid = ObjectProperty(@objid, 'schemaid')

        if (ObjectProperty(@objid, 'IsMSShipped') = 1 OR

            ObjectProperty(@objid, 'IsSystemTable') = 1)

        begin

            COMMIT TRANSACTION

            raiserror(15001,-1,-1, @objname)

            return 1

        end

    end



    -- System created Date Correlation view and its columns/indexes cannot be renamed.

    if (@objid is not null

        AND @xtype = 'V '

        AND 1 = Isnull((select is_date_correlation_view from sys.views where object_id = @objid), 0)

        )

    begin

        COMMIT TRANSACTION

        raiserror(15168,-1,-1, @objname)

        return 1

    end



    -- FileTable system defined objects and columns cannot be renamed.

    if ((@objtype = 'object'

        AND exists (select object_id from sys.filetable_system_defined_objects where object_id = @objid))

        OR 

        (@objtype = 'index'

        AND exists (select object_id from sys.filetable_system_defined_objects where object_id = @cnstid))

        OR

        (@objtype = 'column' 

        AND exists (select object_id from sys.tables where object_id = @objid and is_filetable = 1)))

    begin

        COMMIT TRANSACTION

        set @objnameLen = len(@objname);

        raiserror(3865,-1,-1,@objnameLen,@objname)

        return 1

    end



    -- make sure orig no longer shows null

    if @objtypeIN is null

        select @objtypeIN = @objtype



    -- Check for name clashing with existing name(s)

    if (@newname <> @UnqualOldName)

    begin

        -- column name clash?

        if (@objtype = 'column')

            if (ColumnProperty(@objid, @newname, 'isidentity') is not null)

                select @UnqualOldName = NULL

        -- index name clash?

        if ( (@objtype = 'object' AND @xtype in ('PK','UQ'))

                OR @objtype = 'index')

            if indexproperty(@objid, @newname, 'IndexID') is not null 



                select @UnqualOldName = NULL

        -- cnst name clash?

        if (@objtype = 'object' OR @cnstid IS NOT null)

            if (object_id(QuoteName(schema_name(@schid)) +'.'+ QuoteName(@newname), 'local') is not null)

                select @UnqualOldName = NULL

        -- stop on clash

        if (@UnqualOldName is null)

        begin

            COMMIT TRANSACTION

            raiserror(15335,-1,-1,@newname,@objtypeIN)

            return 1

        end

    end



    --------------------------------------------------------------------------

    --------------------  PHASE 32:  Temporay Table Isssue -------------------

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------

    -- Disallow renaming object to or from a temp name (starts with #)

    if (@objtype = 'object' AND

        (substring(@newname,1,1) = N'#' OR

        substring(object_name(@objid),1,1) = N'#'))

    begin

        COMMIT TRANSACTION

        raiserror(15600,-1,-1, 'sys.sp_rename')

        return 1

    end



    --------------------------------------------------------------------------

    --------------------  PHASE 34:  Cautionary messages  --------------------

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------



    if @objtype = 'column'

    begin

        -- Check for Dependencies: No column rename if enforced dependency on column

        if exists (select * from sys.sql_dependencies d where

            d.referenced_major_id = @objid

            AND d.referenced_minor_id = @colid

            AND d.class = 1

            -- filter dependencies where the dependent object d.object_id is a date correlation view.

            -- Date correlation view owner is the same as of any of the tables they are dependent upon so user having alter access

            -- to any of the participating tables will have catalog view access to the MPIV for the following query to succeed.

            AND 0 = Isnull((select is_date_correlation_view from sys.views o where o.object_id =  d.object_id), 0)

            )

        begin

            COMMIT TRANSACTION

            raiserror(15336,-1,-1, @objname)

            return 1

        end

    end

    else if @objtype = 'object'

    begin

        -- Check for Dependencies: No RENAME or CHANGEOWNER of OBJECT when exists:

        if exists (select * from sys.sql_dependencies d where

            d.referenced_major_id = @objid      -- A dependency on this object

            AND d.class > 0     -- that is enforced

            AND @objid <> d.object_id       -- that isn't a self-reference (self-references don't use object name)

            -- filter dependencies where the dependent object d.object_id is a date correlation view.

            AND 0 = Isnull((select is_date_correlation_view from sys.views o where o.object_id =  d.object_id), 0)

            -- And isn't a reference from a child object (also don't use object name)           

            -- As we might not have permission on the dependent object, we list all the child

            -- objects of the object to be renamed and make sure that child object id is not the depending object here.

            AND 0 = (select count(*) from sys.objects o where o.parent_object_id = @objid and o.object_id = d.object_id)

            )

        begin

            COMMIT TRANSACTION

            raiserror(15336,-1,-1, @objname)

            return 1

        end

    end



    -- WITH DEFERRED RESOLUTION, sql_dependencies  IS NOT VERY ACCURATE, SO WE ALSO

    --  RAISE THIS WARNING **UNCONDITIONALLY**, EVEN FOR NON-OBJECT RENAMES

    raiserror(15477,-1,-1)



    -- warn about dependencies...

    if (@objtype = 'objects'

        and exists (select * from sys.sql_dependencies d where 

                        d.referenced_major_id = @objid

                        -- filter dependencies where the dependent object d.object_id is a date correlation view.

                        AND 0 = Isnull((select is_date_correlation_view from sys.views o where o.object_id =  d.object_id), 0)

                        ))

        raiserror(15337,-1,-1)



    --------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ---------------------  PHASE 40:  Update system tables  ------------------

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------



    -- DO THE UPDATES --    

    if (@objtype = 'userdatatype')                      -------- change type name

    begin



        EXEC %%ScalarType(ID = @xusertype).SetName(Name = @newname)

        if @@error <> 0

        begin

            COMMIT TRANSACTION

            raiserror(15335,-1,-1,@newname,@objtypeIN)

            return 1

        end



        -- EMDEventType(x_eet_Rename), EMDUniversalClass( x_eunc_Type), src major id, src minor id, src name

        -- -1 means ignore target stuff, target major id, target minor id, target name,

        -- # of parameters, 5 parameters

        EXEC %%System().FireTrigger(ID = 241, ID = 6, ID = @xusertype, ID = 0, Value = @UnqualOldName,

            ID = -1, ID = 0, ID = 0, Value = NULL, 

            ID = 3, Value = @objname, Value = @newname, Value = @objtypeINOrig, Value = NULL, Value = NULL, Value = NULL, Value = NULL)



    end

    else if (@objtype = 'object')                       -------- change object name

    begin



        -- update the object name

        EXEC %%Object(ID = @objid).SetName(Name = @newname)

        if @@error <> 0

        begin

            COMMIT TRANSACTION

            raiserror(15335,-1,-1,@newname,@objtypeIN)

            return 1

        end



        -- EMDEventType(x_eet_Rename), EMDUniversalClass( x_eunc_Table), src major id, src minor id, src name

        -- -1 means ignore target stuff, target major id, target minor id, target name,

        -- # of parameters, 5 parameters

        EXEC %%System().FireTrigger(ID = 241, ID = 1, ID = @objid, ID = 0, Value = @UnqualOldName,

            ID = -1, ID = 0, ID = 0, Value = NULL, ID = 3,

            Value = @objname, Value = @newname, Value = @objtypeINOrig, Value = NULL, Value = NULL, Value = NULL, Value = NULL)



    end

    else if (@objtype in ('index', 'statistics'))                       -------- change index name

    begin       

        -- update the index or statistics name, and change object name if cnst      

        declare @last_error int

        EXEC %%IndexOrStats(ObjectID = @objid, Name = @UnqualOldName).SetName(Name = @newname)

        set @last_error = @@error

        if @last_error <> 0

        begin

            COMMIT TRANSACTION

            declare @len int = 2*len(@newname)

            if @last_error = 4              

                raiserror(12802,-1,2, @len, @newname, 100)

            else

            raiserror(15335,-1,-1,@newname,@objtypeIN)

            return 1

        end



        -- EMDEventType(x_eet_Rename), EMDUniversalClass( x_eunc_Index | x_eunc_Stats), src major id, src minor id, src name

        -- -1 means ignore target stuff, target major id, target minor id, target name,

        -- # of parameters, 5 parameters

        declare @eunc int

        if (@objtype = 'index')

            set @eunc = 7;

        else if (@objtype = 'statistics') 

            set @eunc = 9;



        EXEC %%System().FireTrigger(ID = 241, ID = @eunc, ID = @objid, ID = @indexstatsid, Value = @UnqualOldName,

            ID = 1, ID = @objid, ID = 0, Value = NULL, ID = 3,

            Value = @objname, Value = @newname, Value = @objtypeINOrig, Value = NULL, Value = NULL, Value = NULL, Value = NULL)

    end 

    else if (@objtype = 'column')                       -------- change column name

    begin

        EXEC %%ColumnEx(ObjectID = @objid, Name = @UnqualOldName).SetName(Name = @newname)



        if @@error <> 0

        begin

            COMMIT TRANSACTION

            return 1

        end



        -- EMDEventType(x_eet_Rename), EMDUniversalClass(x_eunc_Table), src major id, src minor id, src name

        -- -1 means ignore target stuff, target major id, target minor id, target name,

        -- # of parameters, 5 parameters

        EXEC %%System().FireTrigger(ID = 241, ID = 1, ID = @objid, ID = @colid, Value = @UnqualOldName,

            ID = 1, ID = @objid, ID = 0, Value = NULL, ID = 3,

            Value = @objname, Value = @newname, Value = @objtypeINOrig, Value = NULL, Value = NULL, Value = NULL, Value = NULL)

    end



    COMMIT TRANSACTION



    -- Success --

    return 0 -- sp_rename
```

Comment: Thank u for answer Gameiswar.. I was execute " sp_helptext 'sp_rename' " But, i can not able to understand that.. please explain it..

Comment: **sp_helptext** will return actual code which you have written in store procedure. Where as sp_rename will rename the database name as i said above.

Comment: Thank u for comment saddam_msp. I have one more doubt..? what is use of log file on sql server?  where is it? and if I did delete log file what will be happen?